# How to make controllers map to POST request in codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3, php-7, php-5.6

I wanted to handle post request seperately for controllers in codeigniter. Their doc says you can add http verb after route name to specify it something like that.
`$route['first-route']['GET']= user/first-route`

I added it for my post request form but it is returning 403 status.
This is the route.

`$route['create_user']['POST']='examples/dummy';`

This is the function for it.

```
public function dummy()
 {
    echo 'got this thing';
 }
```

But when I hit request through POSTMAN or doing FORM Submission I am getting 403 response code

Comment: No I am not. I am using php 7.3 and still I am not able to map the controllers specifically to post or get method

Comment: Why did you tag it with PHP 5 then?